# How to launch .desktop file from terminal

Tags: command-line, .desktop

I have a file on my desktop named "Firefox - Profile B.desktop". I am running Firefox in profile A. I tell Firefox Profile A to run a command in terminal. I'm trying to make it launch "Firefox - Profile B.desktop" so this start the second profile. Can you please help

I discovered this: `awk -F= '/Exec=/{system($2)}' "/home/noit/Desktop/Mozilla Firefox - dev.desktop~"` but it's waiting for me to close that profile after it launches. :(

This is a video showing my desktop files. I'm trying to launch them somehow so that the file descriptors don't mix between each other per this StackOverflow topic: [Close all File Handles when Calling posix_spawn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21952155/1828637). And here is my screen cast: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yc19BzLTnDE

Thanks

Comment: i actually did this a while back but i found no way and i don't think there is for firefox to run 2 profiles at the same time

Comment: Thanks @ΝίκοςΦυτίλης well I can run them at same time. I just launch it from terminal like this: `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox -no-remote -P "NAME OF PROFILE HERE"` so i have profiles named dev and default so i launch with `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox -no-remote -P dev` and `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox -no-remote -P default` it works from terminal. But I'm trying to execute it from Firefox Profile A. I'm having a tricky time though because the PID of the launched process gets its PID on the file descriptors open by the launching process. Im trying to avoid this file descriptor share.

Comment: Btw this is for the addon Profilist whose goal is to launch multi profiles, it works but im just trying to keep the PIDs clean because I need this for a feature in next version of Profilist, which is testing if profile is running by testing fcntl on lock files. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/profilist/

Comment: This is a video showing my desktop files. I'm trying to launch them somehow so that the file descriptors don't mix between each other per this StackOverflow topic: [Close all File Handles when Calling posix_spawn](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21952155/1828637). And here is my screen cast: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yc19BzLTnDE